# Trust Computer With Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, watchos, trust

As I'm preparing to transport my app to my watch for debugging I miss the popup or prompt that allows my watch to trust my computer. Now it show, "Not Ready for Development" errors. How would I allow my Apple Watch to trust my computer

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was restart.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Restart the watch
- Restart the mac